# How to add new button on my page in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

[image]

I want to add new button on my page how can add ? sharepoint designer Please check attched screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you didn't write if it is for edit or new form. But Let's say it is for both or for one of those forms.

- You can do it by opening SharePoint designer 2013,
- on the left side menu choose Lists and libraries, choose the list in which you want to create this new button.
- Than, when main window refreshes and lists' options are visible to you, look at right column on second window from up where it says **Forms**.
- There is a button **New..**  Choose if you want Edit form or New form, give name to that form and click OK.
- After that a new form will be created in the list of Forms.
- Right click on it and choose Edit in Advanced mode.
- Than take a look at the image bellow, Find `ms-toolbar` in code and you will see in your code something similar to that

[image]

You just need to add part from **Start** to **End** with additional actions for your new button. Outcome is on the second image.

[image]

Comment: if this is appropriate solution for you, please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I find the easiest way (if you're wanting it on the page itdself) is to create a content editor web part and use HTML if that's the case and you not familiar with HTML then I can help or you can use W3. Alternatively use a promotoed links list web part if you want multiple links and the button would be an image.