# how can I add a button to the ribbon of a SharePoint 2013 designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer

how can I add a button to the ribbon of a SharePoint 2013 list without [image]

Comment: 0
down vote
 

Use the Page Title to find the page using SharePoint Desinger then, edit the Html of the page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add new button on my page in sharepoint 2013](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/189764/how-to-add-new-button-on-my-page-in-sharepoint-2013)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create one Custom Action to add one button in Ribbon.
You can add this by using SharePoint Designer at ease and for that Please refer this [link](http://www.abelsolutions.com/creating-a-custom-action-in-2-steps-with-sharepoint-designer/) which shows each step with understanding.

Comment: Please up vote answer..